# Microsoft Word macro to alter heading styles

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to create a macro in Word that alters the style of a set of ~150 unique headings. All styles must be identical. My current code works and changes the formatting correctly, but only one heading at a time. 
Simply put, it's ugly.

I'm looking for something I can reuse, and possibly apply to more projects in the future.

Maybe using the `loop` command? I don't know, I'm still somewhat new using VBA.

```
Sub QOS_Headings()
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim head1 As Style, head2 As Style, head3 As Style, head4 As Style
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set head1 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    Set head2 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")

With objDoc.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Section A.^p"
    With .Replacement
    .ClearFormatting
    .Style = head1
    End With
    .Execute Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceOne
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You have two tasks. One is to find a text, the other to apply a style to it. Since the style is the same for all you can safely concentrate on specifying the text. If you google for something like "find all occurrences" you will find code to loop through your text. You should make this work. Then you can apply a format to each bit of text you find. Note my choice of words. I say "apply a format", not replace a text with a format as your code suggests. That won't work. I also strenuously avoid the word "select" because you will be better off using the `Range` object.

Comment: Ok the looping bit is helpful-- however the codes I am attempting to find are all unique. Any thoughts on how I might code a macro to find multiple string values that don't repeat anywhere? Alternatively it would work to enter all values I wish to find, but just once, and then execute the style code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no way in which you can identify the heads you want automatically you may have to write everything once. Create a separate function for this purpose. It might look like this:-

```
Private Function SearchCriteria() As String()

    Dim Fun(6) As String                 ' Fun = Designated Function return value

    ' The number of elements in the Dim statement must be equal to
    ' the number of elements actually declared:
      ' observe that the actual number of elements is one greater
      ' than the index because the latter starts at 0
    Fun(0) = "Text 1"
    Fun(1) = "Text 2"
    Fun(2) = "Text 3"
    Fun(3) = "Text 4"
    Fun(4) = "Text 5"
    Fun(5) = "Text 6"
    Fun(6) = "Text 7"

    SearchCriteria = Fun
End Function
```

You can add as many elements as you wish. In theory it is enough if they are unique within the document. I shall add some practical concerns below. Use the code below to test the above function.

```
Private Sub TestSearchCriteria()

    Dim Crits() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Crits = SearchCriteria
    For i = 0 To UBound(Crits)
        ' prints to the Immediate Window:
        ' select from View tab or press Ctl+G
        Debug.Print Crits(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Now you are ready to try to actually work on your document. Here is the code. It will not effect any changes. It's just the infrastructure for testing and getting ready.

```
Sub ChangeTextFormat()

    Dim Crits() As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    Crits = SearchCriteria
    For i = 0 To UBound(Crits)
        ' find the Text in the document
        Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Content
        With Rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Execute FindText:=Crits(i), Forward:=True, _
                     Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop
            Fnd = .Found
        End With

        If Fnd = True Then
            With Rng
                Debug.Print .Text
'                .MoveStart wdWord, -2
'                With .Font
'                    .Italic = True
'                    .Bold = True
'                End With
            End With
        Else
            Debug.Print "Didn't find " & Crits(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The first half of the procedure will find each of the search criteria in your document using the same kind of loop as you already know from the test procedure. But now the text is fed to the `Find` method which assigns the found text to the `Rng` range. If the item is found you now have a handle on it by the name of `Rng`.

The second half of the sub deals with the outcome of the search. If the text was found the found text (that is `Rng.Text`) is printed to the Immediate window, otherwise the original text `Crits(i)` with "didn't find".

If the text was found you want to assign a style to it. But before you can do so you should deal with the difference between the text you found and the text you want to format. This difference could be physical, like you didn't write the entire length of the text in the criteria, or technical, like excluding paragraph marks. In my above sub there is just random code (extending the `Rng` by two preceding words and formatting everything as bold italics). Consider this code a placeholder.

For your purposes code like this might do the job, perhaps. `.Paragraphs(1).Style = Head1` Actually, that is rather a different question, and I urge you not to rush for this result too fast. The part you now have needs thorough testing first.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you for the detailed response.